# Switching between layers DAL and WebService with same interface

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, interface

I have a new application that I need to distribute it locally (local area network) and the web.
However, I need to maintain the safety and quality of performance in both environments.

At first, I thought:

[image: Idea about layers]

So I thought I'd separate the layers of my application in Class Libraries, the Data Access, Interface/Contract Layer and Intermediate Layers.
The Intermediate Layer where the application would choose between working directly with DAL or the WebService.

So, I have:

The Model Layer:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Model
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Car
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Interface/Contract Layer:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Contracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICarContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Model.Car Get(int carId);
    }
}
```

The Data Access Layer (DAL):

```
using System.Linq;

namespace DAL
{
    public class CarRepository : Contracts.ICarContract
    {
        public Model.Car Get(int carId)
        {
            var ctx = new Context();
            try
            {
                return ctx.Cars.First(x=>x.Id == carId);
            }
            finally
            {
                ctx.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}

using System.Data.Entity;

namespace DAL
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Model.Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The WebService, in a WCF WebService Hosted in IIS:

```
using System;

namespace WSL
{
    public class CarService : Contracts.ICarContract
    {
        public Model.Car Get(int carId)
        {
            return new DAL.CarRepository().Get(carId);;
        }
    }
}
```

The WinForms App:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WFApp
{
    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetButtom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int carId = Convert.ToInt32(carIdTextBox.Text);
            var rep = new IntermediateLayer.Car();
            var car = rep.Get(carId);
            carNameTextBox.Text = car.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the Intermediate Layer:

```
using System;

namespace IntermediateLayer
{
    public class Car : Contracts.ICarContract
    {
        public Model.Car Get(int carId)
        {
            ?????
        }
    }
}
```

Well, all this is to show that the desire to keep the presentation layer / view / Forms, changing the intermediate layer.

My question is: This is possible? How make this?
It´s a good practice? No? How do you recommend me to solve this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How make this? I would say you have to use [**IOC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx) for an example of C# implementation. Is this a good practice? IMO absolutely yes (your _intermediate_ level is just a **service** layer in a 4-tiers application). Of course you may simply remove this layer (if it doesn't add any logic/abstraction) and go straight to your business layer implementing a **Repository** (using IOC to pick right source).

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try.

Comment: IOC does, however, add significant complexity to your application, as would maintaining two code paths. Is there a reason that your local clients cannot also hit the service layer? Perhaps with different auth? Also, @Adriano, your link is legacy as stated in the "Retired Content" block at the top of the page.

Comment: @BrianP IOC doesn't add (much) more complexity than what he wrote so far. To make it easy it's just: I use an interface, I'll pick concrete types according to configuration settings. I know link is outdated, it's just an example about how it could be implemented and what it is. According to his application complexity there are a wide range of options, even a type full qualified name from app.config may be viable...

Comment: Hi Brian! The idea of local clients to access the DAL directly would be for performance.

Comment: @Tiago yes and it may abstract even more: web service, direct access to DAL objects or even different pluggable DAL layer (think about, for example, protocols for SQL Server connections). That said if you're using WCF you have a good abstraction above media (and you may need to worry about performance only if you're really moving a lot of data).

Comment: For my experience (then, of course, limited to scenarios I met) I used this only when I needed to switch between very different implementations (for example a small and optimized SQL CE database and a fully featured SQL Server installation) and when I had to support older computers. I don't like the price I have to pay in my business layer (extra code for repository, code for everything else is more or less of same complexity).

Comment: Indeed, in simple transactions, with only webService everything would be simpler. But yes I will have cases of large data transfers.

Comment: @Adriano, please! That the "full qualified type name from app.config" would be a way to be able to use one or another assembly? Ie, create a Class Library with access to the DAL and another with access to WebService? So having a way to use one or the other?

Comment: @Tiago well...yes, it is! You have an interface IContract, implemented by class Direct (direct access) and ServiceBased (access through web service). Your code _see_ IContract but concrete instance comes from app.config (yes yes with Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType()) if it's enough). Not so different from classes/interfaces relations for System.Data objects (connections, commands and so on). Of course it's simpliest case (I can't say if it applies to you or not and you may need to change something in design too) but...